# How to get the data consumed by the consumer in RabbitMQ Queues

Tags: java, rabbitmq, vert.x

We want to restrict the data consumers consume daily while they're consuming messages from the queue. RabbitMQ monitoring has something to do with the number of messages from the queue and is not based on the consumption of the consumer Ex: prefetch count. Monitoring frameworks like Prometheus would take whatever data RabbitMQ supplies or takes up generic metrics. Is there any way in which we could form a specific metric so as to know the consumption of that user or are there any tools online that help us to do that?

I tried looking at the information about consumer utilization here: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/rabbitmq-monitoring/#metric-to-alert-on-consumer-utilization

Comment: Ensure that the management plugin is enabled in your RabbitMQ installation. This plugin provides an HTTP API for accessing metrics and management features.

Comment: The management plugin tells the memory / number of bytes in the queue but it's short lived... It is said that `It only stores recent data (think hours, not days or months)`

Comment: Enable RabbitMQ Event Exchange: RabbitMQ has an event exchange that allows you to record a variety of events such as queue creation, message publishing, and message consuming. To capture these events and store them externally for analysis and historical reference, you can build a separate queue tied to the event exchange.